# Trouble with NaNs: set_index().reset_index() corrupts data

Tags: indexing, pandas, nan

I read that NaNs are problematic, but the following causes an actual corruption of my data, rather than an error. Is this a bug? Have I missed something basic in the documentation?
I would like the second command to give an error or to give the same response as the first command:

```
ipdb> df
    year  PRuid  QC       data
18  2007  nonQC   0  8.014261
19  2008  nonQC   0  7.859152
20  2010  nonQC   0  7.468260
21  1985     10 NaN  0.861403
22  1985     11 NaN  0.878531
23  1985     12 NaN  0.842704
24  1985     13 NaN  0.785877
25  1985     24   1  0.730625
26  1985     35 NaN  0.816686
27  1985     46 NaN  0.819271
28  1985     47 NaN  0.807050
ipdb> df.set_index(['year','PRuid','QC']).reset_index()
    year  PRuid  QC       data
0   2007  nonQC   0  8.014261
1   2008  nonQC   0  7.859152
2   2010  nonQC   0  7.468260
3   1985     10   1  0.861403
4   1985     11   1  0.878531
5   1985     12   1  0.842704
6   1985     13   1  0.785877
7   1985     24   1  0.730625
8   1985     35   1  0.816686
9   1985     46   1  0.819271
10  1985     47   1  0.807050
```

The value of "QC" is actually changed to 1 from NaN where it should be NaN.

Btw, for symmetry I added the ".reset_index()", but the data corruption is introduced by set_index.

And in case this is interesting, the version is:

```
pd.version
<module 'pandas.version' from '/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pandas-0.10.1-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg/pandas/version.pyc'>
```

Comment: Indexes with Nan values sound buggy. I'm on 0.11 and set_index displays me the NaN values on QC index level. However looking at reset_index source code shows that `self.index.labels` and  `self.index.levels` do not returned correct NaN values. I would recommend you to file a bug to the Pandas team.

Comment: Thanks. Okay, I filed one at https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/3586

Comment: and fixed by this: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/3587, was a bug, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this was a bug. By the end of May 2013, pandas 0.11.1 should be released with the bug fix (see comments on this question).
 In the mean time, I avoided using a value with NaNs in any multiindex, for instance by using some other flag value (-99) for the NaNs in the column 'QC'.