# Unexpected assignment in dataframe columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am mocking the data with pandas dataframe, code below:

```
import pandas as pd
from random import randrange

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['YYYYMM'] = pd.Series(3*list(pd.date_range(start="1/1/2019", end="12/1/2020", freq="MS")))
df['Regions'] = pd.Series(['NA', 'EMEA', 'APAC']).repeat(24).reset_index()[0]

df_emea = df[df['Regions'] == 'EMEA'].copy()
df_emea["YYYYMM"] = df_emea["YYYYMM"].repeat(3).reset_index()['YYYYMM']
df_emea["country"] = pd.Series(24*['UK', 'Germany', 'France']).reset_index()[0]

df_na = df[df['Regions'] == 'NA'].copy()
df_na["YYYYMM"] = df_na["YYYYMM"].repeat(2).reset_index()['YYYYMM']
df_na["Country"] = pd.Series(24*['Canada', 'USA']).reset_index()[0]

df_apac = df[df['Regions'] == 'APAC'].copy()
df_apac["YYYYMM"] = df_apac["YYYYMM"].repeat(2).reset_index()['YYYYMM']
df_apac["Country"] = pd.Series(24*['China', 'Japan']).reset_index()[0]
```

Everything works fine except `df_apac`. Somehow I have `None` in `Country` column and NaT in `YYYYMM` column:

[image: have]

Can someone explain why it is so?

Comment: Remove the `freq="MS"` param from your fourth line of code.

Comment: @etch_45, thanks for your comment, why should I remove it? It's stands for month start.

Comment: Interesting. This looks like a bug similar to this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16511319/trouble-with-nans-set-index-reset-index-corrupts-data) a while back that also involved `df.reset_index` and data corruption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an indexing problem. As you do not reset the index of the initial df_xxx dataframes they keep the indices they had in the initial dataframe. So when you later try to add new columns the indices are misaligned.

So a quick fix is to use:

```
df_emea = df[df['Regions'] == 'EMEA'].copy().reset_index(drop=True)
...
df_na = df[df['Regions'] == 'NA'].copy().reset_index(drop=True)
...
df_apac = df[df['Regions'] == 'APAC'].copy().reset_index(drop=True)
...
```

I now gives the expected result for `df_apac` but you are still stuck with only 48 rows for `df_emea` where you would need 72 to accept 3 countries. But it may meet you requirement...

Comment: Thanks, that's helped me.